# Using different criteria for vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

so I'm having difficulty understanding how to set up a vlookup formula in an instance where I might have two different identifiers.

For instance, if I have a table where the first column is the ID of a product, and the second column is the UPC code of a product, If I want to vlookup the product name, is there a way to either use the ID OR the UPC?

If I input an ID one time and the UPC a second time, is there a way to construct a vlookup that searches for both and if found, then populates the field with the correct name?

[Here is an image of a part of what I am trying to work with. I want to populate the product name using either the order number OR the UPC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9VCP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply nest it inside an `IFERROR`. Assuming `K2` contains your lookup value, which can be the `Order Number` or `UPC`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K2,$A$2:$C$13,3,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K2,$B$2:$C$13,2,FALSE),"Not found"))
```

This looks up the product name by Order Number first, then UPC. If it can't be found as either, return "Not found"

Comment: Thank you! I'm working out a few kinks to make it work more the way I need it to, but otherwise the logic makes sense and I'm finally past that wall!

Answer (score 0):

simply do not use vlookup!

```
=MIN(IF((A20=A2:A18)+(LEN(A20)=0),IF((B20=B2:B18)+(LEN(B20)=0),ROW(2:18))))
```

> This is an array formula und must be confirmed with Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

It will output the first row number which matchs "order number" abd "upc" while the order number to look for is in A20 and the upc is in B20. Empty A20 / B20 will be true for all rows. With a simple INDEX you can get the output you desire like:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MIN(IF((A20=A2:A18)+(LEN(A20)=0),IF((B20=B2:B18)+(LEN(B20)=0),ROW(2:18)))))
```

> This is an array formula und must be confirmed with Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

This will output the first item in column C which match the criteria.

If you still have questions, just ask.